# Why getting following error TypeError: jQuery(...).validate is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a folloing validation code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    jQuery("#commentform").validate({
        rules: {      
            author: "required",          
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            comment: "required"
        },
        messages: {
          author: "Author name required",
          email: "Email required",
          comment: "Comment required"
        }
    });
  });    
    </script>
```

I got an error message in console when I run the code

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).validate is not a function
```

Is this not function?

Comment: Are you loading the jQuery validate plugin correctly, before you call this code?

Comment: You need to add the validation library of jquery.

Comment: I added following jquary libraries        <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.appear.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>

Comment: Apparently not, or you would not be getting this error.  Check your JavaScript console for 404 errors.